# How to save custom structures in Hexplorer?

Tags: windows, hex-editor

I've got pretty used to a freeware hex editor called "Hexplorer". I set up custom structures to describe and analyze custom binary formats. However, it seems these structures can exist only in current session. If I try to open another instance of Hexplorer, these structures are gone. The only place the structures show in is the instance used for structures creation. The structures are pretty complex and I do not want to lose it. Does it write structures automatically or only when closed? And how can I make those formats be recognised using `Crypto => File Type` command? If it is even possible?

Comment: These are all good questions, but you probably ought to be sending them to the author of the application via https://github.com/adhoc2

Comment: @spikey_richie Isn't author of the program Polish? [Marcin Dudek](http://artemis.wszib.edu.pl/~mdudek/) claims to be creator. However, I'll ask maybe both authors. I did screenshot of both binary format header structures, which means I can recreate them. Thank you, anyway.

Comment: @spikey_richie After reading the `Readme.md` file in GitHub repository, I have to inform you that this is different program. The program I was talking about is hexadecimal editor used for binary analysis and editing. You linked me to source code of some editor for diesel engine program files :D [This](https://sourceforge.net/projects/hexplorer/) is the program I was talking about.

Comment: In that case, maybe here? https://sourceforge.net/p/hexplorer/discussion/

Comment: @spikey_richie Already did and got answer :)